# How to implement a Safari Extension in Mac

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, safari-extension

I am Senior iOS Mobile Application Developer, but i got the requirement to implement a Extension(Plugin) for Safari Browser. So can any one help me how do i start with and what are the tools i should use. I am aware of X-Code, iOS, Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)